# How to validate if records are inserting /updating through external tool(dataloader,workbench) and not from UI

Tags: apex, trigger, api, code

I have requirement where i need to run method inside trigger only when if records are inserting/updating through UI not from (DataLoader/Workbench).
Please suggest if we have any solution ..Not able to find as such

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user data uploads and make all the data uplaods going forward from the same user hence specifying the ID in the Trigger / Custom Metadata / Custom Settings.

Another option is to create a custom setting, and then perform the data uploads during a time when no users are using the ORG, then disable the custom settings, and perform the data upload.

There is one more option, where you can create a Profile just for data uploads / Permission Sets / Custom Permission, which you can give to the user with you are performing the Data Upload. and in the trigger check if that permission exists on the current user.